# Problems with queries

Tags: mysql, schema, table

I have problems with queries in MySQL.

Problem 1:

Query:

```
SELECT * FROM information_schema.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA="mysql" and TABLE_NAME="servers"
```

MySQL says:

> #1054 - Unknown column 'mysql' in 'where clause'

Problem 2:

Query:

```
desc servers; // command no work
```

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The double quote `"` is actually specifying a field or an identifier.  Use single quotes to specify your *string* filters:

```
SELECT *
FROM information_schema.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA='mysql'
AND TABLE_NAME='servers'
;
```

Problem #2 could be you are `USE`ing the wrong database.

For example, if your table *servers* is in the schema *mysql* and you are currently using `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` and you try to `DESC SERVERS;` you will receive an error.  To get around this you can fully qualify your table name (in this example `DESC mysql.servers`) or `USE <schema_name_here>` and then issue your `DESC SERVERS;` command.

Try explicitly spelling it out: `DESCRIBE mysql.servers;`  Also, make sure that you are using the correct case for your table names.  `Servers`, `SERVERS`, and `servers` are all different in MySQL.

Comment: About problem 1, it is curious that on a server if it works with double quotes and not in another. You know that it may be? (Same servers, miasma version of CentOS, etc).

Comment: @JoseMiguel different sql mode settings - [ANSI_QUOTES](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_ansi_quotes) is responsible for that.